# .htaccess not passing GET parameters

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I have a *.htaccess* file that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php? [L,R=301]
```

However when I do any get parameters such as `/login?random=get&params=true` they don't get passed through to the `login.php` file. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php? [L,R=301]

You need to remove the `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution. This is effectively creating an *empty* query string, removing anything that is passed in the request.

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php [L,R=301]
```